# Understanding ng-repeat for array of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following array of objects, which is a server response. I am trying to use `ng-repeat` to iterate over this array and read each value.

While trying to use in html, `array[0].value` is working while using `ng-repeat`, nothing is working.

After a lot of debugging, I am unable to understand how ng-repeat is working for arrays.

Here is my example:

messages array:

```
[
{"Id":14,"Text":"hii hello","count":750},
{"Id":10009,"Text":"test message","count":6}
]
```

The following is used in html:

```
<div  class="my-message" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
       {{messages}} <!-- printing the above array -->
        <div ng-repat="message in messages">
       {{ message.Id}}<!-- printing nothing -->

</div>
{{ messages[0].Id }} <!-- printing 14 !-->
</div>
```

The array is in scope and it is also seen in this html as the {{ message }} array is printing properly.

Can someone help me understand the working of ng-repeat and where am I missing

Comment: typo in `ng-repat` (should be `ng-repeat`)?

Comment: my bad on syntax.thanks

Comment: expose the array on scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with typo in using "ng-repeat", after correcting it my code worked normally as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you must have :

```
$scope.messages = [{"Id":1,...},...]
```

There is a typo in your view code (ng-repat -> ng-repeat):

```
<div ng-repat="message in messages">
    {{ message.Id}}
</div>
```

must be :

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    {{ message.Id}}
</div>
```

It should be fine like this.

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

hope this will clears you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div  class="my-message" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
       {{messages}} <!-- printing the above array -->
        <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
       {{ message.Id}}
         {{ message.Text }} 
         {{ message.count }} 
</div>
</div>
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.messages =[
{"Id":14,"Text":"hii hello","count":750},
{"Id":10009,"Text":"test message","count":6}
];
 
});
</script>
</html>
```